# node-inspector not working from generator-angular-fullstack app

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, node-inspector

I'm pretty new to grunt, and created a new app using generator-angular-fullstack and yeoman. I'm trying to figure out how to debug.

When I run grunt serve:debug, I get a Chrome window with http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858

I then open my application at http://localhost:9000 in another Chrome tab.

Two issues though:

1. If I set a break point, the debugger never hits it
2. I can only set breakpoints in client side js, not server side

Thanks for any help